# Smart and efficient replace with linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have

```
Dictionary<string,string> keyValList;
```

its data looks like:

```
<"{1}" , "TEXT NUMBER 1">
<"{2}" , "TEXT NUMBER 2">
<"{3}" , "TEXT NUMBER 3">
<"{4}" , "TEXT NUMBER 4">
<"{5}" , "TEXT NUMBER 5">
<"{5}" , "TEXT NUMBER 6">
```

I have List of objects that has this text in it:

```
Item item1 = new Item();
item1.Tooltip = "{1}";
item1.Label= "{2}";
item1.Error= "{3}";

Item item2 = new Item();
item2.Tooltip = "{4}";
item2.Label= "{5}";
item2.Error= "{6}";

List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(item1);
items.Add(item2);
```

What is the smartest way to make `items`(!) look like this:

```
   item1.Tooltip = "TEXT NUMBER 1";
   item1.Label= "TEXT NUMBER 2";
   item1.Error= "TEXT NUMBER 3";
   item2.Tooltip = "TEXT NUMBER 4";
   item2.Label= "TEXT NUMBER 5";
   item2.Error= "TEXT NUMBER 6";
```

I am looking in to an efficiant way, because this is just an example, the `items` and `keyValList` are bigger.

Thanks

Comment: Bad raters, why dont you explain what is wrong with this question?

Comment: Stack Overflowers are a fickle bunch, you never know what will set them off. ;)

Comment: They won't, they just like to give minuses :) However, I can see one flaw in your question that may irritate them - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your title and tags are not a great match for the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you wanna do that in linq ?

```
foreach(Item item in items) {
  item.Tooltip = keyValList[item.Tooltip];
  item.Label = keyValList[item.Label];
  item.Error = keyValList[item.Error];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
items.ForEach(item => {
    int idx = items.IndexOf(item);
    item.Tooltip = keyValList["{" + (idx*3+1).ToString() + "}"],
    item.Label = keyValList["{" + (idx*3+2).ToString() + "}"],
    item.Error  = keyValList["{" + (idx*3+3).ToString() + "}"]
});
```

Comment: I think you have an off-by-1 error here. `"{0}"` will turn up missing.

Comment: Read the question again. The item's properties already contains the keys to the text to be mapped to.